# ajax not firing on click in back button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, back-button

I'm creating a mobile app with AngularJS and ionic framework, i have a category page filled with data loaded with ajax (see code below) , when i click to one category, page containing category posts is displayed (content is loaded with ajax also)  , when i click to back button (to category page), the ajax refuse to return data, but the success function is executed.
I would like how to fix this behavior.

```
.controller('SubMenuCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state,$stateParams,$rootScope){
  $scope.itemsSubMenu = {};

  id = $stateParams.ID;
  id_cat1 = $stateParams.id_cat;

  var responsePromise = $http.get("http://monguidepratique.com/mobile/getCategories.php?parent_id="+id+"&id_cat="+id_cat1);

  responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {     
    alert('data'+id +' '+id_cat1);
    if(data.category=='category' ) {
      $scope.itemsSubMenu = data.catgs;
    } else {
      alert('redirect');
      $state.go('app.postpage',{'id_cat':id_cat1});
    }
  });
  responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("AJAX failed!");
  });   
})
```

And this is my state:

```
 .state('app.menuitempage', {
  url: "/menuitempage/:ID/:id_cat",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/menuitempage.html",
      controller: 'SubMenuCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

and this is mycategory.html page

```
<ion-view title="category item">
 <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive" >
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c" >
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>


<ion-content  class="has-header">
  <ion-list >
   <ion-item   ng-repeat="menusubitem in itemsSubMenu"  ng-href="#/app/menuitempage/{{menusubitem.ID}}/{{menusubitem.id_cat}}">
     <a class="item-icon-right">{{menusubitem.title}}<i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Why the ajax is not returning a result when i click to back button , contrary to the default behavior?

Comment: up, if my problem is not clear please let me know